# When does the Approaching SharePoint Storage Limit email get issued?

Tags: sharepoint-online, notifications, storage-quota

Does anyone know when the notification goes out when storage capacity has breached the percentage threshold? Does it go out as soon as it's recognized that the current usage has surpassed the threshold setting? Or... is this a notice that is sent at the end of the week?  (Asking because ironically received two notices on Saturday - one for an actual site, and another on a test site that had breached it's threshold a week prior.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the email is sent weekly, on Saturday. I don't know if this is configured, or just how the system works. But my two test sites issued emails on Saturday for 2 straight weekends.